# Problems with boot after installation

Tags: system-installation, boot, laptop

I'm trying to install elementary OS on a laptop with a windows 8.1 instalation. I wanted to erase everything from the windows installation  and then install nicely the elementary OS on it.

I've mounted the iso in a usb stick and proceeded to installation. When asked about partitions, I choosed "delete everything and install E OS" (or something like it, it was the second option on the menu anyway).

So after everything is downloaded I'm asked to reboot the machine to complete. After, the laptop shows that theres no windows boot manager present and no other boot available to choose from.

What should I do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm facing the same thing, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I looked for an answer to your question, I found something here : [How do I install Ubuntu on a computer without an OS on it? [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231719/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-computer-without-an-os-on-it)

I just googled "how to install linux on a laptop with no os or boot menu"

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to repair the grub using this link:
http://www.fosslinux.com/1521/boot-repair-for-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-elementary-os-can-fix-bootloader-issues.htm

Hope this helps you.